# Why my task has 0x5 Access denied exit code with Task Scheduler if script was finished?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-task, task-scheduler, scheduling

I have following batch script:

```
copy \\remotehost.ip\c$\dumps\TEST_%date%.dmp C:\dumps\TEST_%date%.dmp

sqlplus sys/password as SYSDBA  @C:\dumps\recreate_test.sql > C:\dumps\recreate_test.log

timeout /t 10

impdp system/password@sid schemas=TEST,TEST_VIEW directory=dumps_dir dumpfile=TEST_%date%.dmp logfile=impdpTEST_%date%.log
```

It copy sql dmp file from remote host in the same network. Then run script that recreate users in database:

```
shutdown immediate;
startup restrict;

drop user TEST cascade;
drop user TEST_VIEW cascade;

create user TEST identified by password;
create user TEST_VIEW identified by password;

grant all privileges to TEST;
grant all privileges to TEST_VIEW;

EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'TEST');
EXEC DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'TEST_VIEW');

shutdown immediate;
startup;

exit;
```

Then run import script. All this SQL have got log files and it seems everything runs good. I have got some errors during import, but they just told me that user already exists ([`ORA-31684`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_31684_import_impdp.htm)) and import everything in this existing user and also got [`ORA-39082`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_39082_object_type_created_with_compilatoin_errors.htm) error, which was meant to be fixed with `DBMS_UTILITY` (yes, I see my error here, but it's not the point) later.

I run it with highest privileges. System administrator allowed me to check option `Run whether user is logged on or not` and option `Do not store password`. It has 0x5 code even if I run task manually selecting `Run` from dropdown menu in Task Scheduler.

Why my task ends with 0x5 error code if everything runs good? I've seen logs, they're good.